# PS Script to output members of targetted groups into a file

Tags: powershell, user

I have an auditing / documentation requirement around my SP Environment upon which members of specific groups need to be listed.  Now, rather than doing this manually via screen-shots and / or cut and pastes, I'd like to set-up a utility in PS that'll do this for me and can be referred to in the literature.

To this end, I'd like to create a PowerShell script that will take the name of a user group and will output the members of that group into a file.

I've got a few scripts that output user groups and all users per site collection but nothing that allows me to be more surgical in targeting a specific group at a time.

As such, if anyone has a script or a reference to one that I can toy with, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create your script and save it to a file such as ListAllUsersInGroup.ps1

```
$site = Get-SPSite <UrlToSiteCollection>
$groups = $site.RootWeb.sitegroups

foreach ($group in $groups) 
{
    if ($group.name -eq "My Group")
    {    
        foreach ($user in $group.users) 
        {
            "  User: " + $user.name
        }
    } 
}

$site.Dispose()
```

Then you can run the script doing the following letting the output go to file.txt like this

```
PS > .\ListAllUsersInGroup.ps1 > file.txt
```

This outputs the result in the same location as your script with the desired information:

[image]

Comment: Perfect.  I thought piping would sort it but this works perfectly.